# Calling s3cmd with django-celery

Tags: django, subprocess, celery, s3cmd

I have these lines within a django application. They run fine under normal conditions, but when I call them as a celery task nothing seems to happen. I can't even find an error reported. Could anyone suggest where I could be going wrong?

```
cmd = "/path/to/unzipped_s3cmd/s3cmd get s3://%s %s/"
subprocess.call(cmd % (s3path,localpath), shell=True)
```

I am running the celery task under the django user.

Comment: On a somewhat different note - I can really recommend using the boto library for interfacing with AWS services http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

It may be because module `subprocess` don't imported into your function. It means the celery task not saw module `subprocess` because the task would be run into the own process/thread/greenlet.

Example:

> ```
> @task
> def some_function():
>     import subprocess
>     cmd = "/path/to/unzipped_s3cmd/s3cmd get s3://%s %s/"
>     sp = subprocess.call(cmd % (s3path,localpath), shell=True)
>     return sp.returncode
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It must have something to do with the path to s3cmd or user permissions I guess. I have just installed s3cmd using the ubuntu package depository instead of doing a local unzip and it works fine with celery now.